# VB.net Get parameter value on html

Tags: html, vb.net

Hi i am working on getting some values from an HTML file. I tried using htmlagility but it seems that it cant id the values i am looking for. Here is a sample of the content:

```html
<td pvalue="9" columnid="presentation" role="gridCell" class="dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0-0 field-ResourceIAQStats nPresentedContacts">9</td><td pvalue="8" columnid="presentation" role="gridCell" class="dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0-1 field-ResourceIAQStats nHandledContacts">8</td>
```

I want to get the values under pvalue. Here is my initial code. Im trying to use ReadAllText function. I know if im not doing it right. Any help would be appreciated.

```
        Dim text As String = File.ReadAllText("D:\Downloads\ifr.htm")
        Dim searchtxt As String = "field-ResourceIAQStats avgTalkDuration"">"
        Dim index As Integer = text.IndexOf(searchtxt)
        If index >= 0 Then
            MsgBox(Microsoft.VisualBasic.(text.Substring(index)))
        End If
```

**EDIT:**

I used this code for XML / XPath query.

```
        Dim nav As XPathNavigator
        Dim docNav As XPathDocument
        Dim NodeIter As XPathNodeIterator
        Dim strExpression As String

        'Open the XML.
        docNav = New XPathDocument("D:\Downloads\ifr.htm")

        'Create a navigator to query with XPath.
        nav = docNav.CreateNavigator

        strExpression = "//td[@class='dgrid-cell dgrid-cell-padding dgrid-column-0-3 field-ResourceIAQStats longestTalkDuration'"
        NodeIter = nav.Select(strExpression)
        MsgBox(NodeIter.Current.Value)
```

Comment: Is your HTM file well-formed enough to be read as XML? If so, then you can use .NET XML parsing to find the attribute of the td element matching your criteria (or simple XPath query).

Comment: Already tried using XML and XPath query but it gives me an error:
"The ';' character, hexadecimal value 0x3B, cannot be included in a name"

Comment: You may also try mshtml